# Sailsjs update model json

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Let's say there is a a user model defined like this.

```
...
attributes: {
    properties: {
        type: 'json',
        required: true,
        defaultsTo: {
            canEdit: {
                owned: false,
                other: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update `user.properties.canEdit.owned` and `user.properties.canEdit.other`?

Comment: go ahead and move your solution to a new answer and accept it yourself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done this way.

```
User
.findOne()
.where({ ... })
.then(function(user) {
    user.properties.canEdit.owned = true;
    user.properties.canEdit.other = false;
    user.save(function(err) { ... });
});
```